# How to extends abstract class from template in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, templates

I have an architecture like that and I want to extends my `TemplateService` with a template but actually I have an error on it. Is there a way to extends an abstract class from a template ?

```
// Error message
ReferenceError: Service is not defined
abstract class TemplateService<Service> extends Service
                                               ^
```

```js
// My code
abstract class TemplateService<Service> extends Service { // Cannot find name 'Service'.
    constructor() {
        const name = "Hello world !";

        super(name);
    }

    public getJob(): string {
        return "Job";
    }

    protected getAge(): number {
        return 25;
    }
}

class ImportedService {
    constructor(private _name: string) {}

    public getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
}

class MyService extends TemplateService<ImportedService> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public fooMethod(): void {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @jasie _Cannot find name 'Service'._ on _extends Service_ in the abstract class prototype.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error (including stack trace) there, not as comment. Maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: It really is true that there is no class constructor named `Service` in existence; TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, which has classes, but no generics.  So that compiles to `class TemplateService extends Service {}`, and what is `Service`?  I think what you're trying to do here is implement a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), but unfortunately TS's mixin support will only let you do this where the constructor parameters are passed straight through to the base class; the thing you're doing with `name` is not going to be easily representable.

Comment: So maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzOD4w) might meet your needs, but it really involves slapping the compiler several times inside the implementation of the mixin function in order to get the types kind of right.  Let me know if that works for you and I might right up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, it works. I just changed the [typing](https://tsplay.dev/NDkAlw) a bit to avoid any.

Comment: @jcalz The only problem is that we doesn't have access to TemplateService public methods.

Comment: Demonstrate this with a [mre] in the question, please, if it’s a requirement.  Make the example have every feature you need to accept or reject an answer. As I mentioned, the compiler doesn’t want to let you do this so you’ll need a type assertion and to spell out the relevant types.  I can show this but only if the example code motivates it.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7OVnN) meet your needs?  Note that exporting private/protected members from functions is not going to work with declaration files, so I'm not sure if you need that or not.

Comment: @jcalz Yes it's good like that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a category error to write

```
abstract class TemplateService<Service> extends Service {}
```

TypeScript's static type system, including [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript that actually runs.  In the above, `abstract` and `<Service>` are part of the static type system, while the rest is valid JavaScript (at least for modern versions of JavaScript).  Your code as written would be emitted to something like

```
class TemplateService extends Service {}
```

which hopefully shows the problem.  Unless there happens to be a class constructor named `Service` in scope, this would be a runtime error.  You can't subclass a *type*; you need to subclass a *constructor value*.

---

TypeScript has some support for subclassing an arbitrary constructor value via the concept of [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html).  Instead of writing `TemplateService` as a class, you make it a class *factory function* that accepts a class constructor as an input.  Conceptually it would look like

```
// don't write this, it's not valid TS
function TemplateService<C extends new (name: string) => object>(ctor: C) {
    return class extends ctor {  // error!
// ------> ~~~~~
        constructor() {
            const name = "Hello world !";
            super(name);
        }
        public getJob(): string {
            return "Job";
        }

        protected getAge(): number {
            return 25;
        }
    };
}
```

And you'd use it like

```
class ImportedService {
    constructor(private _name: string) { }

    public getName() {
        return this._name;
    }
}

class MyService extends TemplateService(ImportedService) {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public fooMethod(): void {
        console.log(this.getName());
        console.log(this.getJob());
        console.log(this.getAge())
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript's mixin support assumes that you are going to just pass the constructor parameters through, so the above `TemplateService` implementation gives compiler errors.  There are open issues about this, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#37142](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37142).  For now all I could say is to work around it by using several [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to trick the compiler into allowing the mixin and into to giving it the correct type.

For the particular example code here, it could look like:

```
function TemplateService<C extends new (name: string) => object>(ctor: C) {
    const c = class extends (ctor as new (...args: any) => object) {
        constructor() {
            const name = "Hello world !";
            super(name);
        }
        public getJob(): string {
            return "Job";
        }

        protected getAge(): number {
            return 25;
        }
    };

    return c as {
        new(): InstanceType<C> & InstanceType<typeof c>;
    }
}
```

Now the compiler believes that `TemplateService(ImportedService)` is a no-arg constructor which produces instances of a combination (via [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)) of `ImportedService` and the type of the anonymous class expression with a `getJob()` method and `protected getAge()` method.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#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-w8Z8kEEO4qCQBBqnvKIdSQNg+VKTRpBfN8+WvW9tAIxVYjYzAOKQLiePfS4tiSITmlY9jOO419pLjW5BMGH9CzXMRcixVBAJQhMCKgPkyIoqiaI1AB6GzUCKEoygqCgqlqAAaVAtk8v5CzMy541s+z0jwBA2DCSgmDCYQNDoVApNQN9UEjaNziAA)